# Android: Draw a view on canvas

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I have a view inflated, I can draw it on canvas, but can't seem to position it properly.

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = li.inflate(R.layout.fix_this_recommendation, null);
v.measure(MeasureSpec.getSize(v.getMeasuredWidth()), MeasureSpec.getSize(v.getMeasuredHeight()));
v.layout(400, 400, 400, 400);
v.draw(canvas);
```

But the view is always at the top left corner. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each View draws its contents within its own coordinate system, with (0, 0) at the top-left. If you want it to appear elsewhere, you can set a new [transformation matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#setMatrix%28android.graphics.Matrix%29) on your Canvas.

Comment: That make sense now, the issue was the subviews are not drawing properly. So what does "layout" do then?

Comment: Is there any info on how to exactly do this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 14):

Solution is to translate canvas:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(left, top);            
view.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: No need in matrices!

Answer (score 1):

because the coordinate system used in the `Canvas` starts from the  top left  corner instead of doing that define your Custom View and override the [`onDraw()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) method and inside it position your view as you like

Comment: This is what I am doing, the code above is inside the onDraw() function. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

use drawChild(canvas,child,getDrawingTime()); instead of child.draw(canvas)

drawChild will calc child's top and left margin